# How do I read multiple times from same line in stdin?

Tags: c, scanf

I want to read multiple times from the same line in C, for example, my input would be

```
1 2 3
```

and I want to read it like

```
scanf("%d" , a);
scanf("%d%d" , b, c);
```

If I do it like this I get a runtime error, in pascal I just use read instead of readln, here it goes to the second row automatically, and in second row there isn't anything, that's why I get a runtime error I guess...

Comment: Because for example if I don't know in one row if I have 1 or more values, for example I have for input
1 a a
2
1 b c
I would have to first read the first number, if it's one I read again for other 2 values, if it's 2 I don't read anymore. If I try to read 3 times when it's '2' I will also get a runtime error

Comment: it should be `scanf("%d" , &a);
scanf("%d%d" , &b, &c);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `scanf("%d" , &a); scanf("%d%d" , &b, &c);`, and `scanf()` just stops at the newline or other whitespace character in the buffer, it didn't go to the second row automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry not for posting this as a comment but i aint allowed to do so!

Why wouldn't you just store it in a variable and then you can do your parsing?
No need to call scanf twice for handling data from the same line.